# SQL Update with join when 1 table looks like duplicates but isn't

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

I'm struggling with a join between 2 SQL tables where: 
1 table (OrderItems) contains 2 different item lines for the same SKU and Quantity
and the other table (DespatchTable) contains data about which SKU/Qty has been despatched.

I need to populate the Despatch table with the relevant item number fro the OrderItems table. Usually this is easy when the SKU only exists once, but as you can see from the example below, I have a situation where the same SKU exists on 2 different lines so when I only have Consignment, SKU and Qty to join on it's updating both records of Despatch.ItemNumber to the same item number - I need these to be different (It doesn't actually matter which item number gets assigned to which despatch line, as long as they are unique)

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnN1F.png]

```
UPDATE d
SET ItemNumber= oi.ItemNumber
FROM DespatchTable d
    INNER JOIN OrderItems oi
        ON d.ConsignmentNumber = oi.ConsignmentNumber
           AND d.SKU = oi.Sku
           AND d.Quantity = oi.Quantity
```

Can anyone suggest the best approach to this issue as I'm not in control of the data in either table so have to work with what I've got. It's also worth mentioning that although I've narrowed it down to 2 lines, there are always other SKUs on the same consignment.

Comment: Hi, Apologies, I should have clarified that. I'm using SSMS 2016

Comment: SSMS is an IDE, @NickRoberts , not an RDBMS. SQL Server is the RDBMS here.

Comment: Is quantity always an exact match or could one line item in `OrderItems` for five widgets be dispatched as three blue widgets and two clear widgets? If another line item is for 10 widgets could the items dispatched be combined, e.g. seven green widgets and eight paisley widgets would satisfy the order for `5 + 10` widgets?

Comment: Hi @HABO - The despatch quantity would always be equal to or less than the order line quantity; For example the item lines could be 5 and 8 and it would be possible to receive despatch quantities for 5 and 4. In this instance, I'd prefer to despatch the 'whole' item line and partially despatch the line of 8 (therefore leaving 4 left to despatch)